# Scalable Alternatives to Web Scraping & Cron Jobs

Tags: php, curl, cron, web-scraping

So I have a small project that I made for a couple friends. Nothing too complex, it's essentially just a PHP script that sends a cURL POST request to a web page (to be specific, it's a search page and each of my friends has different search parameters), scrapes the search results and sends my four friends and I email notifications if the results contain a certain keyword using preg_match - unfortunately the website does not have an API for this.

Currently I'm executing this script every minute (with a cron job) on my small 512 MB LAMP DO VPS. Doing this uses about 50% of its memory, which brings up my question: are there any memory-efficient ways of revamping this project which would allow for it to scale to support, say, hundreds of users? I realize that I'll have to invest in upgrading my server, but with my current stack it would just be incredibly expensive.

Basically I'm wondering if there would be a better method to forge a search request to the web page (and scrape the results), as well as a better alternative to a cron job executing the task every minute.

Also, I'm open to switching languages. I only used PHP because I'm most familiar with it.

Comment: So, no concern at all for memory use and upgrading cost for the website/server you're scraping from - in particular hundreds of users later?

Comment: What kind of method of measurement did you use that showed you that a PHP CLI command running `curl_exec`, `preg_match` and `mail` uses 256 MB of RAM? Despite the fact PHP is rather wasteful with memory, that still seems off.